# How do I fix dragging window lag?

Tags: 20.04, graphics, framerate

Whenever I drag a window in Ubuntu, the dragging process isn't smooth.

My refresh rate is set to 144Hz.

Please help; I don't want some complex type of help (i.e., Compiz).

My GPU is MSI 1060 6 GB. Also, my NVIDIA driver is 460 (Propriety, tested).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04 with Xcfe4, simply turning on "Enable display compositing" fixed the issue for me.

Settings > Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor

Answer (score 0):

My problem with Ubuntu 22.04 and Gnome running on X with proprietary NVIDIA drivers was fixed by *deactivating hardware acceleration in Discord*.

The problem might be with any chromium/electron app as suggested in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ud2l2l/2204_freezinglagging_when_dragging_windows/).